# "realloc(): Invalid pointer" error

Tags: c, memory, realloc

I'm working on some code for school, and here's the fragment of code that I'm having some trouble with:

```
// Create file path
int size_path = 11;
char* path = malloc(size_path*sizeof(char));
path = "./storage/\0";
for(i = 0; i < size_filename; i++){
    size_path++;
    path = realloc(path, size_path*sizeof(char));
    path[size_path-1] = filename[i];
}
path[size_path] = '\0';
```

Essentially, what I am doing is trying to find the existence of a file (for example, `test.txt`) and so I need to use `access()` to check it's existence, but first I need to build the `path` itself such that `path = "./storage/test.txt"` I've already used the method above to parse some other stuff, so I know the way I'm doing it works, I just think I'm missing something here because whenever I try to run the code, I get an error in the compiler: `*** Error in ./a.out: realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000004016c7 ***`

I'm curious to see what insight you guys can provide me because I've been working on this bug for at least a half hour though and the community has helped me solve numerous problems in a matter of minutes, so I'm sure it's just an off-by-one thing but I can't really figure out where it would be.   Thanks in advance!

EDIT: As I imagined, I got the answer to my question in under 5 minutes.  Turns out, I was accidentally leaking the dynamically allocated memory by not actually putting anything into it and statically allocating it directly afterwards.  Instead, I've used `strcpy(path, "./storage/")` and I got exactly the functionality I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: Read [ask] and specifically the part about [homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: `path = "./storage/\0";` assigns `path` which was just initialized with `char* path = malloc(size_path*sizeof(char));`  That leaks the previous allocation.

Comment: Presumably, `path = "./storage/\0";` should be `strcpy(path, "./storage/");`

Comment: `strcpy(path, "./storage/");` same effect as `strcpy(path, "./storage/\0");`

Comment: `realloc(path, size_path*sizeof(char));` too small for final `path[size_path] = '\0';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* path = malloc(size_path*sizeof(char));
path = "./storage/\0";
```

So path points to some dynamically allocated memory, then on the next line you say `path = something_else` so:

1. You've leaked the dynamically allocated memory (because you don't have a pointer to it anymore, so can't get access to it to `free` it)
2. You can't `realloc` non dynamic memory

Reading between the lines of the question, I'd suggest you don't even need dynamic memory at all. You can just use a fixed size buffer:

```
char path[128]; // arbitrary limit that we "know" is ok given our data
char* filename = "test.txt";
sprintf(path, "/storage/%s", filename);
```

Obviously this is tailored to assume filename could actually change based on some data, otherwise the whole lot could be one literal string.

Comment: this is exactly what I figured, and so presumably, like the commenter said above, I should use `strcpy()` to get the string that I want into the allocated memory.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you actually need dynamic memory in the first place? You certainly don't need `realloc`. You could just use a fixed size buffer as a starting point...

Comment: I suppose you're right; I could use a fixed buffer and get the same result.  Either way I'm glad I know now for the future when this problem arises

Comment: @M.M buffer overflow is "addressed" in the comments. Why do you think it truncates filenames with spaces? `scanf` might do odd things with spaces, `sprintf` shouldn't.

Comment: @John3136 My bad